# How to show a custom error message on entering an email input field with other than english language (like arabic)

Tags: forms, angular6, angular2-form-validation

We have a application with supporting two languages (english,arabic) and in the registration form we need to support both the languages. But only for email field we need to show error message use english to enter email field. How can i do this? Any solution will be grate helpful for us . thank you.

```
<form name="enrollmentform" #enrollmentform="ngForm" novalidate>
    <div class='field-container'>
        <input type="text" value="" size="25" maxlength="30"  placeholder="fullname" [dir]="direction"  name="fullname" required #first_name="ngModel" class="floating-input"/>
        <div *ngIf="enrollmentform.submitted && full_name.invalid" class="error">
        <div class="error-message" *ngIf="first_name.errors.required">{{'First Name is required' | translate}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='field-container'>
        <input [dir]="direction" type="text" value="" placeholder="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" [pattern]="emailPattern" required #email="ngModel" />
        <div class="error" *ngIf="(email.invalid) && (enrollmentform.submitted || email.dirty || email.touched)">
        <div class="error-message" *ngIf="email.errors.required">{{'Email_is_required' | translate}}</div>
        <div class="error-message" *ngIf="email.errors.pattern">{{'Please_enter_a_valid_email' | translate}}</div>     
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can i show the error message use only english for email when user uses arabic language in email field.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of [angular multi-language application using custom translate pipe](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-language-with-translate-pipe). Use this type of approach.

You can define your error messages, paragraphs, texts in Language files.
Here assets/languageFiles/en.json

```
{
   "TITLE": "My i18n Application (en)"
}
```

assets/languageFiles/en.json

```
{
    "TITLE": "My i18n Application (ua)"
}
```

Translate service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class TranslateService {
   data: any = {};

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   use(lang: string): Promise<{}> {
      return new Promise<{}>((resolve, reject) => {
      const langPath = `assets/languageFiles/${lang || 'en'}.json`;
      this.http.get<{}>(langPath).subscribe(
        translation => {
        this.data = Object.assign({}, translation || {});
        resolve(this.data);
      },
      error => {
        this.data = {};
        resolve(this.data);
      }
    );
  });
 }
}
```

Translate Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from './translate.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'translate',
  pure:false
})
export class TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}
  transform(key: any): any {
    return this.translate.data[key] || key;
  }
}
```

In your html files use in this way using translate file

```
<h1>
  Welcome to {{ 'TITLE' | translate }}!
</h1>
```

And also you can change the language also.

Please refer the example in the stackblitz.